# I'm trying to import 'ta_lib' library in pine script but I'm getting this error "Compilation error. Line 2: no viable alternative at character '@'"

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I want to import ta-lib library in pine script editor of trading view.
My command line is @import "ta_lib"

It shows following error
Compilation error. Line 2: no viable alternative at character '@'

I realised I have to make public library but I dont know how to make it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `@` in the syntax.

You should use the following syntax:

```
import <username>/<libraryName>/<libraryVersion> [as <alias>]
```

Example:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Using AllTimeHighLow library", "", true)
import PineCoders/AllTimeHighLow/1 as allTime

plot(allTime.hi())
plot(allTime.lo())
plot(allTime.hi(close))
```

You can read [this](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Libraries.html#using-a-library) for more.